# How to retrieve the value from a map

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

I need to retrieve value from a map and compare it with return of a method. I'm unable to get the value to perform assertion.

**Step Class**

```
And("^Based on pass message changes$", (DataTable table) -> {
        Map<String,String> row=table.asMaps(String.class,String.class).get(0);
        DummyPage.getDummyPassField().setValue(row.get("Pass"));
        Assert.assertTrue(DummyPage.passStrengthMsg().contains(row.get("Message")));
    });
```

**Scenario**

```
And Based on pass message changes
  |Pass       |Message    |
  |<Pass>     |<Message>  |
Examples:
  |Pass                |Message               |
  |@password.tooLowPass|@StrengthMsg.tooLowMsg|
  |@password.avgPass   |@StrengthMsg.medMsg   |
  |@password.stgPass   |@StrengthMsg.stgMsg   |
  |@password.vsgPass   |@StrengthMsg.vsgMsg   |
```

The pass values are correctly passed by

```
DummyPage.getDummyPassField().setValue(row.get("Pass"));
```

And the method does return expected value

```
DummyPage.passStrengthMsg()
```

But the code to get the value from map doesn't provide the value

```
row.get("Message")
```

Can someone explain why is it so that for `row.get("Pass")` it works and for `row.get("Message")` it doesn't

Comment: Map.get() return the valure associated to the `key` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html - try chaning the `row.get("Message")` to `row.get("Pass")` and see if you get the value back.

Comment: @Jaybro90Changed the key value and the message value got passed. So it is not  issue of passing the value. 
Then the issue is in this line of code
Assert.assertTrue(DummyPage.passStrengthMsg().contains(row.get("Message")));

Comment: try printing the map and check its content (also interesting to see what `row.get("Pass")` is returning) {somehow `get(0)` is suspicious - maybe you must start with `1` and increment it for each test, based on documentation: *The top row is used as keys in the maps, and the rows below are used as values* }

Comment: @CarlosHeubergerBy starting with 1 it will thrown IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: There should be two maps that was created from `Map<String, String> row=table.asMaps(String.class, String.class)` one with the key of `Pass` and the other with the key of `Message`, you're trying to compare the value from `Pass` to the value from `Message` - [unless mistaken](https://static.javadoc.io/info.cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.5/cucumber/api/DataTable.html#asMaps-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-)

Comment: @Jaybro90I'm trying to compare the value from the message with string returned from passStrengthMsg(). Pass value is not used for comparison. It is send to a textbox

Comment: Last thing I can think of is that for whatever reason `row.get("Message")` may not be the exact spelling that `DummyPage.passStrengthMsg()`is, so the `.contains` returns false - try with `DummyPage.passStrengthMsg().equalsIgnoreCase(row.get("Message"))`, cause like you said the `DummyPage.passStrengthMsg()` returns the value its just that the `row.get("Message")` doesn't

Comment: @Jaybro90Did try the equalsIgnoreCase but no success.

Comment: @KK  Why are u using a datatable? Just change the step to - "Based on pass message changes <Pass> and <Message>". Can u add the print out of the List<Map> conversion after using asMaps().